# How to count trains per day?

Tags: counters

In this sentence, how does one read the counters?

> 1日あたり16本運行しています 
> *There are 16 trains per day.* 
> https://www.fnn.jp/articles/417130

I found several answers, such as...

- 1日【にち】あたり16本【ほん】運行【うんこう】しています (https://www.jcinfo.net/en/tools/kana)
- 1 にち-あたり16-ぽん うんこう して います (https://j-talk.com/)
- 日あたり【ひあたり】(2) (日当たり, 日当り, 日当 only) per day (http://wwwjdic.biz/)

My best guess is

- [1日]【いちひ】あたり[16本]【じゅうろっぽん】運行【うんこう】しています

Comment: The question of ほん or ぽん is purely phonetic. It doesn't matter whether the counter is used for trains or, say, pens. If 日 as a measure word was pronounced ひ, 一日 would be いっぴ. In fact, it is sometimes used for ついたち, but not for the period of one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This 1日 is read いちにち. Other readings (ついたち, いちじつ, いっぴ, etc) are incorrect. Although there is a phrase [ひあたり](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%97%A5%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A) ("per day"), this is an independent phrase that cannot be used with a number like "1".
- As for 16本, you can read it either as じゅうろっぽん or じゅうろくほん. Both sound natural, and I don't know which is better.